# Handle null values in BULK COLLECT

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I trying to pass data from table A to table B, but first I need to check if the data I'm trying to insert is not in the table B. I do this with a query if exists will return the identification. The problem is the second execution throws a unique constraint violation so it appears the validation to compare if exist in table B is not working, or the condition in the `if` statement is wrong.

```
  DECLARE

       LN_EXIST       NUMBER;

       CURSOR cur
       IS
            SELECT *
              FROM table_A


       TYPE cur_aat IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE
          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

       cur_rows                cur_aat;
    BEGIN
       OPEN cur;

       LOOP
          FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO cur_rows LIMIT 1000;

          EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;                      /* cause of missing rows */

          FOR I IN 1 .. cur_rows.COUNT
          LOOP
             LN_EXIST := 0;

             BEGIN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION);

                SELECT PUV.PEU_IDENTIFICACION -- check
                         INTO LN_EXIST
                  FROM table_b PUV
                 WHERE (CASE
                           WHEN     PUV.PEU_IDENTIFICACION =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0')
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0')
                                AND PUV.PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                                            '0')
                                AND PUV.PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO
                           THEN
                              'S'
                           ELSE
                              'N'
                        END) = 'S';
             EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS
                THEN
                   LN_EXIST:= 0;
             END;

             IF LN_EXIST!= 0     --if not exist
             THEN
                INSERT
                  INTO table_b (PEU_ID,
                                               PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
                                               PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
                                               PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                                               PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                                               PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
                                               )
                VALUES (cur_rows (I).PEU_ID,     
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
                        );
             END IF;
          END LOOP;

          EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       END LOOP;

       COMMIT;

       CLOSE cur;
    END;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code shown above won't execute because of syntax errors in the lines which read

```
PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
```

and

```
cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
```

The trailing commas will cause the compilation to fail.

Second, row-by-row processing tends to be slow, even when you bulk collect the data into memory from the database. I suggest you use a `MERGE`, which replaces your cursor-and-loop logic with a single statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_B b
  USING TABLE_A a
    ON (b.PEU_IDENTIFICACION = a.PEU_IDENTIFICACION AND
        NVL(b.PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0') = NVL (a.PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0') AND
        NVL (b.PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0') = NVL(a.PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0') AND
        b.PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO = a.PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO AND
        NVL(b.PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, '0') = NVL(a.PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, '0') AND
        b.PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO = a.PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (PEU_ID,
            PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
            PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
            PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
            PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
            PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE)
    VALUES (a.PEU_ID,     
            a.PEU_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
            a.PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
            a.PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
            a.PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
            a.PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
            a.PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Obviously using MERGE syntax won't help if the underlying problem is that *"the condition in the if statement is wrong"*. But this solution has so much less code, which makes it easy to spot bloomers in the implemented logic.

Answer (score 0):

I checked, instead of use a `select` statement only, i added a `count` statement, to determine the total of coincidences that exist with the parameters i set so all the times will return a value if not exist 0 and if exist other value than 0.

```
DECLARE

       LN_EXIST       NUMBER;

       CURSOR cur
       IS
            SELECT *
              FROM table_A


       TYPE cur_aat IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE
          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

       cur_rows                cur_aat;
    BEGIN
       OPEN cur;

       LOOP
          FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO cur_rows LIMIT 1000;

          EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;                      /* cause of missing rows */

          FOR I IN 1 .. cur_rows.COUNT
          LOOP

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION);

                SELECT COUNT (PUV.PEU_IDENTIFICACION) -- check
                         INTO LN_EXIST
                  FROM table_b PUV
                 WHERE (CASE
                           WHEN     PUV.PEU_IDENTIFICACION =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE, '0')
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, '0')
                                AND PUV.PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO
                                AND NVL (PUV.PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, '0') =
                                       NVL (cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                                            '0')
                                AND PUV.PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO =
                                       cur_rows (I).PEU_FECHA_NACIMIENTO
                           THEN
                              'S'
                           ELSE
                              'N'
                        END) = 'S';

             IF LN_EXIST!= 0     --if not exist
             THEN
                INSERT
                  INTO table_b (PEU_ID,
                                               PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
                                               PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
                                               PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                                               PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                                               PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
                                               )
                VALUES (cur_rows (I).PEU_ID,     
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_IDENTIFICACION,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_APELLIDO,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                        cur_rows (I).PEU_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
                        );
             END IF;
          END LOOP;

          EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       END LOOP;

       COMMIT;

       CLOSE cur;
    END;
```